# Integrating Atmosphere with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, push-notification, atmosphere

I want to provide push notifications in a Spring MVC project, using JDK 1.6 targeting all browsers. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474273/push-notification-for-java-web-app) and finally decided to go with [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).
For Server-sent events, My server controller is ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128810/atmosphere-integration-with-spring-mvc-framework?rq=1)):

```
@Controller
public class AtmosphereController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/getTime", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void websockets(final AtmosphereResource atmosphereResource) {

        final HttpServletRequest  request = atmosphereResource.getRequest();
        final HttpServletResponse response = atmosphereResource.getResponse();

        atmosphereResource.suspend();

        final Broadcaster bc = atmosphereResource.getBroadcaster();
        bc.scheduleFixedBroadcast(new Callable<String>() {

            public String call() throws Exception {

                return (new Date()).toString();
            }
        }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

While running, I got `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource]: Specified class is an interface`.
In solution to this, I got [this relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507854/conflicts-within-mvcannotation-driven-in-dispatcher-servlet-configuration). I added this to my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean id= "atmosphereResource"
            class="org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Doing this, also results in a new error:

```
[cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'mvc:annotation-driven' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.]
```

I've also tried [this](http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/Is-anyone-using-Spring-with-this-framework-td4652857.html). Please help me inject [AtmosphereResource](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-AtmosphereResource) in Spring Controller. Do I also need to update **web.xml** or some other configuration file to make it work or what part I'm missing. Please help!
Please also comment on other alternatives to provide Server-Side Events functionality. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your argument-resolvers must be a class like this:

```
public class AtmosphereArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest= webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        return Meteor.build(httpServletRequest).getAtmosphereResource();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
            return AtmosphereResource.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

}
```

and try this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="com.yourpackage.AtmosphereArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 1):

try Atmosphere 2.1.0-RC1 and following this [document](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Configuring-Atmosphere%27s-Classes-Creation-and-Injection) . All you need to do is to add the atmosphere-spring.jar to your dependency.

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: is the argument-resolver correct? Does AtmosphereResourceImpl implements a spring MethodArgumentResolver??